# Strange permission issue for SpamAssassin in LXC container

Tags: permissions, spamassassin, lxc

My mailserver set-up is quite old, but did its job for many years. With the last major update from Debian 9 to 10, `SpamAssassin` stopped working. Today I took the time to search for reasons, and I do not understand what I found.

Running `spamassassin --lint` as `debian-spamd`  fails to load all modules with lines like:

```
Nov  4 13:00:50.573 [5216] warn: plugin: failed to parse plugin (from @INC): Can't locate Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm: lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm: Keine Berechtigung at (eval 115) line 1.
```

Using `strace` I see:

```
stat("lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pmc", 0x7ffc01e14860) = -1 EACCES (Keine Berechtigung)
stat("lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm", 0x7ffc01e14860) = -1 EACCES (Keine Berechtigung)
```

Running `spamassassin --lint` as root reports no issues except a missing Bayes database, which is to be expected. But the actual issue is that it does neither use any of the files denied for `debian-spamd`, which simply do not exist:

```
stat("lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pmc", 0x7ffdafdc1aa0) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
stat("lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm", 0x7ffdafdc1aa0) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
stat("/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pmc", 0x7ffdafdc1aa0) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
stat("/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=29190, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

`namei -om /usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/AskDNS.pm` reveals that this file is accessible by anyone. And in fact, I can e.g. `cat` it as `debian-spamd`. But it is apparently not even tried.

On the other hand I did `find / -type d -name 'lib' -exec namei -om {} \;` and there is neither any ´lib´ folder, which would be inaccessible, nor does `find / -type d | grep lib/Mail` list any matching folders, which might be denied.

The server is a LXC container running current Debian 10.6 as does the host.

Any ideas to further pin down the issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that SpamAssassin first checks `./lib/...` before it checks standard paths. I did my test from `/root`, which is inaccessible for other users, i.e. `.` failed already with `EPERM`. Apparently, this causes SpamAssassin to give up immediately.

Starting SpamAssassin from the home directory of `debian-spamd` succeeded.